# Swift - Bond Framework - one-to-many bind relationship

Tags: swift, reactive, frp, swiftbond

I'm interested in binding a single Observable to multiple receivers.
How can I achieve this concisely?

Currently, I have to resort to binding every property:

```
model.sectionEnabled.map{!$0}.bind(to: vc1.view.reactive.isHidden)
model.sectionEnabled.map{!$0}.bind(to: vc2.view.reactive.isHidden)
model.sectionEnabled.map{!$0}.bind(to: vc3.view.reactive.isHidden)
....
```

What if it would be possible to use the following construct?:

```
model.sectionEnabled.map{!$0}
.bind(to: vc1.view.reactive.isHidden)
.bind(to: vc2.view.reactive.isHidden)
.bind(to: vc3.view.reactive.isHidden)
.bind(to:.......
```

Is it already possible to do such binding with the current implementation of the framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is what you want:

```
if let disabled = model.sectionEnabled.map{!$0} {
    for vc in [vc1, vc2, vc3] {
        disabled.bind(to: vc.view.reactive.isHidden)
    }
}
```